# Query not working after upgrading MySQL

Tags: mysql

The following query worked on an older version of MySQL (can't remember which).

```
SELECT  @r AS _id,
         (
         SELECT  @r := parent
         FROM    t_hierarchy
         WHERE   id = _id
         ) AS parent,
         @l := @l + 1 AS lvl
 FROM    (
         SELECT  @r := 1218,
                 @l := 0,
                 @cl := 0
         ) vars,
         t_hierarchy h
WHERE    @r <> 0
```

Since I upgraded to 5.7, I get the error:

> Unknown column '_id' in 'where clause'

Help anyone?

Comment: Maybe start over, with a sample data set and desired result

Comment: please paste the table structure t_hierarchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seem the alias in where condition are not allowed for mysql 5.7

> An alias can be used in a query select list to give a column a
>   different name. You can use the alias in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING
>   clauses to refer to the column:
>
> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause.
>   This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is
>   evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.

see the related doc http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html